# Java Multi Link Checker Spider - improvements needed

Tags: java, performance, testing, web-crawler

I have following working code (changed here and there so you use your brain when you copy and paste it). I'd like to improve it so it detects all pages that are invalid including domains for sale. It works at about 89% efficiency. If you see anything I could improve by using additional existing libraries or little tweaks that would be awesome.

```
 List all = linkService.getAllLinks();
    notValidLinks = new LinkedList();
    final ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(39867);
    int poolSize = 90;
    int maxPoolSize = 100;
    long keepAliveTime = 40;
    ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize,
            keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

    for (link : all) {
       Thread task = new CheckSite(link);
       tpe.execute(task);
       System.out.println("Task count:" + queue.size());
    }

class CheckSite extends Thread {
    Link link;

    CheckSite(Link link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean notValid = false;
        try {
            log.info(link.getLink() + " " + link.getId());
            URL u = new URL(link.getLink());
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
            huc.setConnectTimeout(40000);
            huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
            huc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");

            huc.connect();
            int code = huc.getResponseCode();

            if (code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                    && code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    && code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP ){
                notValid = true;
                log.info("Invalid code: " + code + " - " + link.getLink());
            }
            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM) {
                log.info(link.getLink() + " Perm move");
            }
            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
                log.info(link.getLink() + " Temp move");
            }

            try {
                if (!notValid) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }

                    notValid = StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(Jsoup.parse(stringBuilder.toString()).text(), "Related Searches");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                   log.error(e.getMessage());
            }

            huc.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            log.info("Malformed URL:" + link.getLink());
            notValid = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("Refused connection | Does not exist:" + link.getLink());
            notValid = true;
        }
        if (notValid) {
            link.setApproved(false);
            link.setDateApproved(null);
            notValidLinks.add(linkService.save(link));

        }
        log.debug("URL Finieshed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Bloom Filter](http://code.google.com/p/java-bloomfilter/) [[wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).This will help you do fast and memory efficient look ups.The problem with Bloom filter is that it will false positives ie. it will tell true for things which are not there.But if Bloom filter says false it's false for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to improve it so it detects all pages that are invalid **including domains for sale**.

I suspect that the highlighted part is impractical.  How is a spider supposed to be able to tell that a domain is for sale?

**FOLLOW UP**

@Mat Banik suggests looking for a particular phrase or checking DNS records as possible solutions.

- A heuristic that checks for a particular phrase will give false positives and false negatives.
- Checking DNS records is tricky will be tricky in Java.  You can do a simple DNS lookup on the hostname part of the URL and check the resulting IP address against a known list of DNS parking site IPs.  But that doesn't tell you if the original hostname is actually for sale.  It might be a real site hosted on the same infrastructure ... or a parked domain that is NOT for sale.

But I guess, if you are prepared to accept some false positives and negatives then it is feasible to try to filter out domains for sale.